# Getting a class instance from a merged interface

Tags: typescript

I read the other day about [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) on typescript and wanted to do some experiments. One of such was declaring an interface that extended `mysql.RowDataPacket`, and merging that with a class to implement methods for it. Then that I'd use that interface/class merge to type the return of a `execute` call. Like so:

```js
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

interface A extends mysql.RowDataPacket {
    id: number
}

class A {
    helloWorld() {
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
}

export const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 4000
});

let conn = await pool.getConnection();
const [rows] = await conn.execute<A[]>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?", [1]);

console.log(rows[0].id) // 1
rows[0].helloWorld() // TypeError: rows[0].helloWorld() is not a function
```

From what I understand this happens because while typescript recognizes the interface and the class as being merged, and will provide type checking as if what is returned by `execute` is an instance of `A` when transpiling, the actual interface returned by execute is only a simple, not merged, object.

What can I do if I wanted for the interface returned by execute to be converted to an instance of the merged interface/class `A`? Is declaring a constructor and assigning each property of the interface returned by `execute` to its respective property in `A` my only option?

Comment: `const [rows] = await conn.execute<A[]>("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?", [1]);` is nonsense

Comment: Did you run it? It works fine

Comment: Passing a type argument explicitly like that is meaningless if it doesn't correspond to a value parameter. There's no way that the connection is going to instantiate your class and so you're just getting back an arbitrary object that doesn't have the method that you defined in the class. `conn.execute<A[]>()` means `conn.execute()`

Comment: Yes I understand that. I did say that in the question, but it is not true that conn.execute<A[]>() means conn.execute() for all purposes. For example vs-code provides auto-completion for the returned object parameters as defined in the interface. At runtime I understand they are the same.

Comment: If you want this to work you have to manually create instances of your class that wrap each of the returned results from the connection execution. But this has nothing to do with declaration emerging at all.

Comment: That was my question, thank you for the answer. Yes, the answer does not have anything to do with declaration merging, the question, however, did. Typescript thinks that rows[0] is an instance of the merged object for example. (I know it is because I passed it as a type parameter, but the transpiler letting me do it is what sparked my curiosity as to if there was a way to make the conversion to the actual merged object without declaring a constructor)